# actually i want to use a title method over a text in f-string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, string-concatenation, f-string

```
     my_favourites=['lamborghini',"sea facing resort",
            '100 b dollar','3D animator']
     line_1='and by that much money i want to own a '.title()+my_favourites[1].title()+' & a 
            '+my_favourites[0].upper()
     print(line_1)
     line_2=f'and by that much money i want to own a {my_favourites[1].title()} & a 
     {my_favourites[0].upper()}'
     print(line-2)
```

#So the problem here is that the concatination works nice but i don't know how to apply the title method to the initial text inside the f-string syntax without assigning that text to an extra variable.

Comment: Why not `"and by that much money i want to own a {my_favourites[1]} & a {my_favourites[0]}".title()`

Comment: but sir I have edited my question so plz check it again actually I am a beginner to python but anyways thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll admit it's a bit weird with f-strings:

```
f"{'and by that much money i want to own a'.title()} {my_favourites[1].title()} & {'a'.title()} {my_favourites[0].upper()}"
```

`str.format` would be more appropriate here I think:

```
"and by that much money i want to own a {} & a {}".title().format(my_favourites[1].title(), my_favourites[0].upper())
```

Comment: thx very much for your help it's people like you who help the beginners to follow their dreams in programming